# phantomjs "ElementNotVisibleException" error on selenium

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am executing a selenium test on a phantomjs where I need to select an item from a dropdown. I have tried using ID and Class name to select the desired item.

I have also tried:

Adding a delay in the test.
Using By.CssSelector method of Selenium driver.

Here is the code for dropdown button:

```
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnNewTransformation" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
        {{'imt_tranformation_action_title' | i18n}}
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
```

Here is the code to find the element using selenium driver:

```
 s_driver.FindElement("//button[@id='btnNewTransformation']").Click();
```

I am new selenium and PhanomJS. Can you please help me out here.
What I am missing here and what should I try?

Comment: How you tried to add delay? Show code

Comment: I tried to add delay using two methods:
1. Thread.Sleep(10000) method.
2.driver.Selenium.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))
But here second one is not working.

Comment: Andorsson, Here I tried to take the screenshot on phantomjs using GetScreenshot() method of selenium driver and found that page is actually not rendering ui itself. It would be better if you could figure out some solution for not rendering UI.

Comment: You can avoid using headless `PhantomJS` and use web-drivers for `Firefox`, `Chrome` ... or look toward `JavaScriptExecutor`